# Replace the value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to replace the numeric value in `drpFPortofCall.SelectedValue.ToString`.
For example, given the string `AEJEA~12060` I want the result to be `AEJEA`. Given the string `INNSA~12430` I want the result to be `INNSA` only. How can I do this?

I tried the following but wasn't able to get through.

```
Dim frmport As String = drpFPortofCall.SelectedValue.ToString 
frmport = frmport.Replace("~", "")
```

Comment: So, you want to replace the ~ (AEJEA12060) only or you just want to extract everything before the ~ (AEJEA)?

Comment: how is it related to c# ?

Comment: Do a SubString up to the index of the ~

Comment: Hi Dmyto Holota,

I only want (AEJEA) and want to remove everything after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Easy and Simple**

Using `IndexOf` you will replace the rest

```
Dim frmport As String = drpFPortofCall.SelectedValue.ToString()
Dim value as String = frmport.Substring(0, frmport.IndexOf("~"))
```

Comment: Thank You Abdul, your code helped me out with the issue.

Comment: @ManavSrivastava Kindly accept this answer and upvote it. Kudos to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract everything until the "~".

Here is an example. And a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rIk1hz).

```
    Dim foo = "AEJEA~12060"
    Dim match = Regex.Match(foo,".+?(?=~)")
    
    Dim x = match.Value
    
    Console.WriteLine("x = " & x)
```

Edit: you will need this import:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm pretty sure `drpFPortofCall.SelectedValue` is [*already a string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue?view=netframework-4.8) (What you have might not be a `ListControl` directly, but it almost certainly inherits this property from it). That is, further calling `.ToString()` from there is silly at best and wasteful at worst.

Moving on from there, it seems like you want everything up to the `~`. One option looks like this:

```
Dim frmport As String = drpFPortofCall.SelectedValue.Split("~"c)(0)
```

But that might be slower. With a little more code we could do it like this, which might be very slightly faster:

```
Dim endIndex As Integer =  drpFPortofCall.SelectedValue.IndexOf("~"c)
Dim frmPort As String = drpFPortofCall.SelectedValue.SubString(0, endIndex)
```

... but you won't notice the difference unless you need to run this on 10s of thousands of inputs.

Finally, the two samples we have are strikingly similar in structure, down to the number of characters in each spot. If you can be sure that all of your data follows this format **exactly**, we can do even better:

```
Dim frmPort As String = drpFPortofCall.SelectedValue.SubString(0, 5)
```